# How to submit javaFX form to JavaEE servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, javafx

I am using JavaFX as thin client as a view technology. Design is like...

- On Client Side:=> (View)      JavaFX with client side validations
- On Server Side:=> (Controller and Model)      Server side validations
  Servlets, WebServices, EJBs, JPA.

  There may be a possible need of HTML5 in future. I chose this design so that the application can scale and meet future needs.
  I have a form with some data which need to be submitted and its values are validated on client side as done in HTML with JavaScript. But after validation how can I submit my form values actually name/value pairs to server side where actual business is done.

  For getting data from server to client web services are good choice. How to send data from client to server on submit a form.

So the question is:-

Is there any `<form  action='server/AuthenticateServlet'></html>` counterpart of html in JavaFX or it should be done using HttpClient like api?

Any other ways to achieve this????

Comment: I have read about CaptainCasa framework but It is very thin client. For every change in view it connects to the server that is unnecessarily making the network busy and can not provide a good performance in a slow connections. Many things could be done in client site. I wan't some javascript like processing on client side.  I don't want to bother server for what I can do on client.

Comment: Your best bet is probably an HttpClient API, such as [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html).